# Does Mule http-request oauth2 requests for token everytime if there is no refresh token?

Tags: java, mule

I have this:

`<http:request-config name="ApiRest" protocol="HTTPS"   doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="rest" host="${api.endpointUrl}" port="443">
    <oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type clientId="${api.client_id}" clientSecret="${api.client_secret}">
        <oauth2:token-request tokenUrl="${api.endpointUrl}/oauth/token" />
    </oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type>
</http:request-config>`

The service doesn't provide refresh token. Would the access_token be saved somewhere and be re-used or it will request for token everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses an in-memory Object Store(https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Object+Stores) for reusing the token. This is configurable and you can provide your own object store if you need persistence etc. by using a token-manager Here is an example: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/292d0938eaac5f63219e7c20f564a9bd66c2bed6/modules/oauth/src/test/resources/client-credentials/client-credentials-full-config-tls-nested.xml

Comment: because I don't have the refresh token and the service doesn't actually give an error status code if the token expires (it always gives 200, the error message is in the response), if I specify `refreshTokenWhen`, would it call the request again? Or it will fail because there's no refresh token?

Comment: turns out if I specify `refreshTokenWhen`, it will call the request again but the `payload` is lost so I have to set the request body to a variable instead.